# How to get a page's featured image from a term slug (same name)

Tags: post-thumbnails, slug

I have this code (that i've inserted into archive.php) that displays a page's content on the corresponding post category archive with the same slug.

`<?php $term = get_queried_object(); ?> <?php $page = get_posts([    'name'      => $term->slug,    'post_type' => 'page']); if ( $page ){ echo $page[0]->post_content; }  ?>`

I'd like to find a way I can use the term slug to display the page's featured image.

Comment: ... and while i'm asking, I'd like to do the same for the page's title, custom fields, date, in fact all the page's meta.

Comment: In response to the original question (and not your comment), if you're referring to the same page in your code, i.e. `$page[0]`, then you could just use functions like [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) to display the page's featured image. E.g. Add `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page[0] );` inside the `if` in your code.

Comment: Thanks Sally, that works. I'll have a go at the other stuff.

Comment: How would I change the thumbnail size?

Comment: `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page[0],'medium' );` isn't working

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Did the `src` value point to the wrong image URL (not the one with the `medium` size)? But I have posted an answer, so check it out and let me know.

Comment: @Sally, the 'medium' attribute wasn't working. The correct image but not the correct size.

Comment: So I supposed all is good now?

Comment: Yep works a treat. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I said in the comments, if you're referring to the page referenced by the `$page[0]` variable, then you could just use [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) like so: (note that I checked if `$page[0]` is set before attempting to use it)

```php
// The HTML/formatting is entirely up to you..
if ( ! empty( $page ) && isset( $page[0] ) ) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page[0] );
    echo '<hr>' . $page[0]->post_content;
}
```

Please check the documentation for more details on using the function, but as for changing the or using a different thumbnail size (the default size is named `post-thumbnail`), just set the second parameter to the name of a registered image size, e.g. `medium` or `a-custom-size`. E.g.

```php
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page[0], 'medium' );
```

And note that featured images or post thumbnails have their own *post* where the type is `attachment`, so if you want to get the ID of a post thumbnail or the attachment post, you can use [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/):

```php
$thumb_post_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $page[0] ); // get the post ID
$thumb_post    = get_post( $thumb_post_id );        // get the full post data

// For debugging purposes:
var_dump( $thumb_post_id, $thumb_post );
```

So actually, once you have the post data (e.g. the one in `$page[0]` and `$thumb_post` above), you could then easily get all the other data for that post like the featured image if any/applicable, title, date, custom fields, categories, etc. Try a `var_dump( $page[0] );` and then you'd see various post data, however, for custom fields and other data not directly available in the post object, you can ask in separate questions. :)

### Additional Notes

`get_the_post_thumbnail()` uses [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) which adds the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes used to make the image responsive (so that the browser could pick the right image to load based on the user's device) — see [Resolution switching: Different sizes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#resolution_switching_different_sizes) on the MDN Web Docs website.

Therefore, in reply to your comment: "*`echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page[0],'medium' );` isn't working*", it's probably actually working, but the browser picked a different image responsively based on the above attributes.

For example in my case, `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page[0], 'medium' )` did output the correct image URL (which became the value of the image's `src` attribute) for the `medium` size (300px wide):

```html
<!-- I wrapped the srcset value for brevity -->
<img width="300" height="205"
    src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/sample-image-300x205.jpg"
    ...
    srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/sample-image-300x205.jpg 300w,
        https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/sample-image-1024x701.jpg 1024w,
        https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/sample-image-768x526.jpg 768w,
        https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/sample-image-1536x1051.jpg 1536w,
        https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/sample-image.jpg 1920w"
    sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" />
```

But my browser's viewport width was 360px, hence the browser picked another image (768px wide) from the `srcset` attribute — and if there was also a 600px image there, then that one would've been used instead of the 768px.

#### Don't want the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes?

Well, that's not a good idea and the MDN Web Docs also stated, "*Using this technique could save mobile users a lot of bandwidth*", so I would suggest you to just keep using that technique, i.e. those two attributes.

However, just so that you know, you can use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) like so to manually generate the `<img>` tag, which then gives you a full control over the HTML. E.g.

```php
$id   = get_post_thumbnail_id( $page[0] );
$data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'medium' );

if ( $data ) {
    echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $data[0] ) . '" width="' . $data[1] . '" height="' . $data[2] . '" alt="">';
}
```

And there's also [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) if you just want to get the URL. E.g.

```php
$url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $page[0], 'medium' );

echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" alt="">';
```

Comment: That was a great answer and explanation, it clears up for me know. Many thanks.